# Spatie Permissions / Laravel - Assigned Permission to Role, Role to User - Middleware doesn't pick up on permissions

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

I am using `Spatie` Permissions for my `Laravel` app. I have assigned permissions to a role, and the role to a user.

When I use `$user->getAllPermissions()` or `$user->getPermissionsViaRoles()` it displays them all in `JSON` format.

However, when I am ensuring they have a certain permission before viewing a route using `Spatie` middleware (permission/can) it says unauthorized.

`Route::get('/admin/users', \App\Http\Livewire\Admin\User\UserList::class)->middleware('permission:view users')->name('admin.users');`

I was wondering how I can make it so it knows the permission is assigned through the users role?

It says best practice is to do it how I've done, rather than assigning permissions direct to users.

I've tried using AI, googling, etc and found no answers.

Comment: Did you add the RoleMiddleware, PermissionMiddleware and RoleOrPermissionMiddleware to your app/Http/Kernel.php? You can check here how to do it in different versions of Laravel https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/middleware#content-package-middleware.

Comment: @Dumitru yep I've done that

Answer (score 0):

are you using the \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class in your kernal.php? I believe that to be required for using the can middleware.